# Create a model with hash password in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bcrypt, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to create a **model in Sequelize** with a **hash password using bcrypt**, and run "sequelize db:migrate" but I can't. I get this error whenever I try to run it. All I need to is have "password" with the hash already done. I don't know where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing. can anybody help me?

```
== 001-user: migrating =======

ERROR: s.replace is not a function
```

I'm using: Sequelize: 6.16.2. Database: Postgres. Node: 15. Bcrypt: 5.0.1

Here is my User model:

```
class User extends Model {
    /**
    * @param {import("../index")} models
    */
    static associate (models) {
        User.belongsTo(models.UserRole, { as: "user_role", foreignKey: "id_user_role" });
    }
}

/**
* @param {import("sequelize").Sequelize} sequelize Connection with the database
*/
function initUser (sequelize) {
    User.init({
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

        user: DataTypes.STRING(30),
        name: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        email: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        password: DataTypes.STRING(100),

        id_user_role: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: sequelize.models.UserRole,
                key: "id"
            }
        },

        deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: false,
        modelName: "User",
        tableName: "user",
        underscored: true,
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(11, "a");

                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            },

            beforeUpdate: async (user) => {
                if (user.password) {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSaltSync(11, "a");

                    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return User;
}

module.exports = { initUser };
```

User migration:

```
module.exports = {
    /**
    * @param {import("sequelize").QueryInterface} queryInterface
    * @param {import("sequelize").DataTypes} Sequelize
    */
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable("user", {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true
            },

            user: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
                allowNull: false
            },

            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
                allowNull: false
            },

            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
                allowNull: false
            },

            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
                allowNull: false
            },

            id_user_role: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                references: { model: UserRole, key: "id" }
            },

            deleted: {
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: false
            }
        });

        await queryInterface.bulkInsert("user", [
            {
                user: "admin", name: "test", email: "test@admin.com", password: "admin", id_user_role: 1
            },
            {
                user: "comum", name: "test", email: "test@comum.com", password: "comum", id_user_role: 2
            },
            {
                user: "regular", name: "test", email: "test@regular.com", password: "comum", id_user_role: 3
            }
        ]);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see where `UserRole` is deifned in this code `references: { model: UserRole, key: "id" }`

Comment: I'm importing from my UserRole models.

Comment: AFAIK Sequelize doesn't use hooks from models in migrations. It uses table names, column options and so on.